# Get order data in an array to JSON encode it in Woocommerce

Tags: php, arrays, json, woocommerce, orders

I have a lot of information I need from the woocommerce function wc_get_order, below is some of it.

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_version = $order_data['version'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
```

How do I put all of it in an array and then JSON_ENCODE?

Do I need to do each value separately like

```
$order_array = array("order id: " . $order_id . ", order currency:" . $order_currency . ", order_version: " . $order_version );
```

or is there a way to loop through an put an array for key:value for each piece of info?

Comment: you mean `json_encode($order_data)`? `$order_data` is alreay an associative array

Answer (score 4):

It depend if you want to customize te keys or not and what is the required output:

1. JSON ENCODE: **Keeping all the data** as it is:

   ```
   // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   // Get the meta data in an unprotected array
   $order_data = $order->get_data();

   // Encoding in json
   $json_order_data = json_encode($order_data);
   ```
2. JSON ENCODE: **Customizing the data**, keeping just some data and changing the array keys:

   ```
   // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   $order_data = []; // Initializing

   // Set the necessary data in an array with custom keys 
   // using WC_Abstract_Order and WC_Order methods
   $order_data['order_id']       = $order->get_id();
   $order_data['parrent_id']     = $order->get_parent_id();
   $order_data['status']         = $order->get_status();
   $order_data['order_currency'] = $order->get_currency();
   $order_data['order_version']  = $order->get_version();
   $order_data['order_payment_method']       = $order->get_payment_method();
   $order_data['order_payment_method_title'] = $order->payment_method_title();
   ## And so on…

   // Encoding in json
   $json_order_data = json_encode($order_data);
   ```
3. A FORMATTED STRING: **Customizing the data** and keeping just some data:

   ```
   // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   $order_data = []; // Initializing

   // Set the necessary data in an array using WC_Abstract_Order and WC_Order methods
   $order_data[] ='order_id: ' . $order->get_id();
   $order_data[] ='parrent_id: ' . $order->get_parent_id();
   $order_data[] ='status: ' . $order->get_status();
   $order_data[] ='order_currency: ' . $order->get_currency();
   $order_data[] ='order_version: ' .  $order->get_version();
   $order_data[] ='order_payment_method: ' .  $order->get_payment_method();
   $order_data[] ='order_payment_method_title: ' .  $order->payment_method_title();
   ## And so on…

   // Convert to coma separated string
   $str_order_data = implode( ', ' . $order_data );
   ```

Related: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)